# How can I enter my nickname in Pokémon Go when it tells me it is not valid?

Tags: pokemon-go

How can I enter my nickname in Pokemon Go? I entered my nickname but it is telling me that it's not valid.

Comment: What does this have to with Warframe?

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a different name.
2. Check if it is valid.
3. Proceed if it is valid, else repeat from step 1.

Good luck!